# Script GAS Spreadsheet - Crear y Descargar PDF guardado en Drive

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-drive

Buen día, he creado una función para guardar en Drive una hoja previamente formateada, he logrado que se guarde a una carpeta de mi elección en Drive, además también puedo enviar dicho archivo *.pdf al correo registrado en una celda, lo único que me falta es poder abrir en HTML mediante un Dialog Custom o en todo caso sólo descargar dicho archivo *.pdf.
El código va como sigue:

```
function CrearPDF(){
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('LP con Seguros'), true);
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var fecha = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");//Captura de la fecha de acuerdo a la zona horaria
var dni = spreadsheet.getRange('\'LP con Seguros\'!B1').getValues();
var nrocuenta = spreadsheet.getRange('\'LP con Seguros\'!C6').getValues();
var correo = spreadsheet.getRange('\'LP con Seguros\'!K13').getValues();
var valRegisSimul=spreadsheet.getRange('\'LP con Seguros\'!P10').getValues();
var nombrePDF = valRegisSimul + " de LP DNI "+dni+" " +fecha+".pdf";

//var r1, c1, r2, c2;
var libroActual = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var nombreHoja = libroActual.getActiveSheet().getName();
var gid = libroActual.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
var ssID = libroActual.getId();
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export"+
                                                        "?format=pdf&"+
                                                        "size=a4&"+
                                                        "portrait=true&"+
                                                        "scale=4&"+
                                                        //"top_margin=0.40&"+
                                                        //"bottom_margin=0.40&"+
                                                        //"left_margin=0.40&"+
                                                        //"right_margin=0.40&"+
                                                        "gridlines=false&"+
                                                        "printnotes=false&"+
                                                        //"pageorder=2&"+
                                                        "horizontal_alignment=CENTER&"+
                                                        "vertical_alignment=TOP&"+
                                                        "printtitle=false&"+
                                                        "sheetnames=false&"+
                                                        "fzr=false&"+
                                                        "fzc=false&"+
                                                        "attachment=false&"+
                                                        "gid=" + gid + "&"+
                                                        "r1=" + 0 + "&"+
                                                        "c1=" + 0 + "&"+
                                                        "r2=" + 62 + "&"+
                                                        "c2=" + 8;

var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();

// Creamos un fichero con el Blob anterior y le cambiamos el nombre 
//var newPdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(response);
//newPdfFile.setName(nombrePDF);//localiza tu pdf en tu Drive :)
//}

var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
var pdf = docurl.getBlob().setName(nombrePDF).getAs('application/pdf');

var folders = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFolders(); // En esta variable se almacenan solo los carpetas del directorio raiz
var nombrecarpeta = "DNIs de LP y Simulaciones";
  if(folders.hasNext() == false)//Para cuando no hay carpetas o folder aún en el Drive
  {
    var NewFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(nombrecarpeta);
    NewFolder.createFile(pdf);
  }
  else //En el caso de que sí haya carpetas o folder en el Drive, los recorre hasta encontrar el nombre "nombrecarpeta" sino lo encuentra la creará y ahí guarda el archivo
  {
    while (folders.hasNext())
    {
      var folder = folders.next();
      if(folder.getName() == nombrecarpeta)// en el caso de que exista una carpeta con el nombre terminamos la iteracion de las carpetas
    {
      var folderid = folder.getId();
      var Transfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
      Transfolder.createFile(pdf);
      break;
    }
    else 
    {// Creamos la carpeta en el caso de que aún no exista y guardamos el archivo en la nueva carpeta
      var NewFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(nombrecarpeta);
      NewFolder.createFile(pdf);
      break;
    }
   }   
  }

spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('LP con Seguros'), true);
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  //Obtiene el nombre del archivo PDF recién creado, así como su contenido
   var archivo = docurl.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').getBytes(); // sin la opción getBytes obtendríamos un archivo sin contenido
   var attach = {fileName:nombrePDF,content:archivo, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

   var subject = valRegisSimul + ' de Crédito Efectivo DNI ' + dni + ' ' + fecha;

   var html = '<body>' + '<strong>' + ' <p>Estimado(a)' + '</strong>' + '</p>' + 
      '<p>A continuación encontrará adjunto el archivo del plan de pagos de su Crédito Efectivo, recuerde siempre realizar los abonos al número de cuenta del préstamo.</p>' + 
      '<p style="text-align: left;">==> El número de cuenta del Crédito Efectivo a donde se deben hacer los abonos es: ' + '<strong>' + nrocuenta + '</strong>' + '</p>' +
      '<p></p>'+
      '<p></p>'+'<p>'+'<strong>' + 'David Ezequiel Salcedo Pablo ' + '</strong>' + '</p>'+
      '<p>'+'<strong>' + 'Asesor de Servicios - Financiera Oh!' + '</strong>' + '</p>'+
      '<p>'+'<strong>' + 'Celular: 976020013' + '</strong>' + '</p>'

  //Muestra un Popup preguntando si deseas enviar la transferencia por correo  
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();



  var response = ui.alert('Se completó el registro correctamente, ¿Desea enviar el plan de pagos al correo registrado: '+ correo + ' ?' + '\n\n' + 'Caso contrario, el archivo ' + nombrePDF + ' sólo se guardará en la carpeta ' + nombrecarpeta + ' de Drive', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  // Si la respuesta es si, mandará el correo, de lo contrario termina el programa
  if (response == ui.Button.YES)
  {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(correo, subject, "Cuerpo", {htmlBody:html, attachments:[attach]});
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Se envió correctamente el plan de pagos al correo '+ correo + '.' + '\n\n' + 'Mencione regreso por seguros y número de cuenta del Crédito efectivo');

     }else
     {
       //Solo por referencia
       Logger.log('El archivo '+ nombrePDF + ' quedó guardado en la carpeta ' + nombrecarpeta + ' de Drive');
     };
  }
```

La idea es que al final del código se adicione una función que me permita descargar dicho pdf a la PC, móvil o tablet o en todo caso como decía anteriormente, poder abrir ese pdf en un Dialog Custom a través de un site de Google. De antemano agradezco mucho las respuestas que pueda recibir.

Answer (score 1):

La llamada [`.createFile()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfileblob) regresa un File. Con ese archivo, puedes llamar [`.getDownloadUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file.html#getdownloadurl) y hacer lo que quieres en el Dialog.

```
var file = NewFolder.createFile(pdf);
Logger.log(file.getDownloadUrl());
```

Por favor avísame si entendí mal y esto no es lo que buscabas.

---

También le quiero avisar que su código puede mejorar muchísimo. Por ejemplo, tienes muchas llamadas duplicadas como

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('LP con Seguros'), true);
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
// ...
var libroActual = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var nombreHoja = libroActual.getActiveSheet().getName();
var gid = libroActual.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
```

que lo podrías cambiar así

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var nombreHoja = 'LP con Seguros';
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(nombreHoja).activate();
var gid = sheet.getSheetId()
```

Sugiero que ya cuando has logrado que funcione todo como quieres, que metes un poquito más tiempo a revisar cómo puedes mejorar el código.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta! 
Apliqué tus sugerencias y logré que el código siga corriendo, pero no puedo lograr descargar el PDF, quisiera que en el mensaje de envío de Correo electrónico me salga un enlace o botón que diga que descargue el PDF.

```SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('Se completó el registro correctamente, ¿Desea enviar el plan de pagos al correo registrado: '+ correo + ' ?' + '\n\n' + 'Caso contrario, el archivo ' + nombrePDF + ' sólo se guardará en la carpeta ' + nombrecarpeta + ' de Drive', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO); ```

Comment: @DxSystem2 Cuál es el problema exactamente? Es que no tienes el botón para descargar? En ese caso, es porque tienes que escribir el HTML para enseñarlo.

Comment: @Diego, lo que deseo es adicionar una línea al mensaje de Enviar correo que diga: Se completó el registro correctamente, '¿Desea enviar el plan de pagos al correo registrado: '+ correo + ' ? Si sólo desea desea descargar el archivo, clic aquí'

Comment: @DxSystem2 Puedes incluir el link en el `.prompt()`, pero va aparecer como texto y no un link que le puedes hacer click. Si quieres eso, tendrás que crear algo en HTML y mostrarlo con [`showModalDialog()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title). Pero eso también va requerir [varios cambios](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs) en el código.

Comment: Hola @Diego, con las indicaciones de @Rubén, hice un diáologo modal y quedó así:
`var file = NewFolder.createFile(pdf);
var url = file.getDownloadUrl();
  var html = '<a href=" + url + " target="_blank">Para descargar el PDF con la simulación de pagos, haz clic aquí</a>';
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  var title = "Descargar PDF de Google Drive";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, title);`
Pero al dar clic me genera Error 400 (Not Found)!!1

Answer (score 0):

NOTA: En el código de la pregunta se incluye varios diálogos y en un comentario a la [respuesta inicial](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/312444/65) se mencionar que se desea incluir un enlace para descargar el archivo generado.

Para incluir un enlace (texto cliqueable) en un diálogo personalizado ("custom dialog") se debe usar **HTML Service** porque el método `alert` sólo muestra texto plano y los botones predefinidos (Sí, No, Aceptar, Cancelar) que se indiquen.

Hay varias formas de utilizar el HTML Service, se puede poner el HTML en un archivo tipo html o se puede general el objeto HTMLOutput con base un String.

Dado que el url para descargar es variable, quizás lo más sencillo sea hacer el HTMLOutput con un String como lo has hecho con el mensaje a enviar por correo porque si optas por usar un archivo deberás usar plantillas y scriptlets lo cual implica mas cosas por aprender.

A continuación un ejemplo muy simple de cómo mostrar un díalogo modal con un enlace

```
function mostrarEnlace() {
  var url = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com';
  var html = '<a href=" + url + " target="_blank">Stack Overflow en español</a>';
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  var title = "Mostrar enlace";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, title);
}
```

Referencia

- [Dialogs and sidebars in G Suite Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)
- [Respuesta](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80245/88163) a [Create a popup in Google spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80213/88163)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora lo probaré

Comment: Hola @Rubén, hice un diáologo modal como me pusiste en el ejemplo y quedó así:  
`var file = NewFolder.createFile(pdf);
var url = file.getDownloadUrl();
var html = '<a href=" + url + " target="_blank">Para descargar el PDF con la simulación de pagos, haz clic aquí</a>';
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  var title = "Descargar PDF de Google Drive";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, title);`  
Pero al dar clic me genera Error 400 (Not Found)!!1, ¿alguna idea? PD. No sé cómo realizar saltos de página :(

Comment: @DxSystem2 Te sugiero publicar una nueva pregunta en la que incluyas un [mcve].

Comment: @DxSystem2 En cuanto a que no sabes cómo realizar saltos de página,si te refieres a saltos de página en los comentarios, no se puede.