# Script GAS Spreadsheet para crear y abrir/descargar PDF de Drive en Custom Dialog

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-drive

Buen día, tengo unos scripts con el que guardo un archivo PDF en una carpeta específica para luego enviarlo por correo electrónico. Todo funciona bien, aunque mi código no esté optimizado. Recientemente puse una [consulta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/312433/script-gas-spreadsheet-crear-y-descargar-pdf-guardado-en-drive) donde me ayudaron a cómo crear un Custom Dialog para que muestre el enlace para descargar el archivo PDF, sin embargo cuando presiono en el enlace me sale automáticamente error 400 con lo cual me es imposible descargar dicho PDF. Aún no logro determinar en qué estoy fallando, además de ello, quisiera que el PDF se visualice en dicho Custom Dialog. El código:

```
function CrearPDF(){
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var nombreHoja = 'LP con Seguros';
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(nombreHoja).activate();
var gid = sheet.getSheetId()

var fecha = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");//Captura de la fecha de acuerdo a la zona horaria
var dni = spreadsheet.getRange('\'LP con Seguros\'!B1').getValues();
var nrocuenta = spreadsheet.getRange('\'LP con Seguros\'!C6').getValues();
var correo = spreadsheet.getRange('\'LP con Seguros\'!K13').getValues();
var valRegisSimul=spreadsheet.getRange('\'LP con Seguros\'!P10').getValues();
var nombrePDF = valRegisSimul + " de LP DNI "+dni+" " +fecha+".pdf";

var ssID = spreadsheet.getId();
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export"+
                                                        "?format=pdf&"+
                                                        "size=a4&"+
                                                        "portrait=true&"+
                                                        "scale=4&"+
                                                        //"top_margin=0.40&"+
                                                        //"bottom_margin=0.40&"+
                                                        //"left_margin=0.40&"+
                                                        //"right_margin=0.40&"+
                                                        "gridlines=false&"+
                                                        "printnotes=false&"+
                                                        //"pageorder=2&"+
                                                        "horizontal_alignment=CENTER&"+
                                                        "vertical_alignment=TOP&"+
                                                        "printtitle=false&"+
                                                        "sheetnames=false&"+
                                                        "fzr=false&"+
                                                        "fzc=false&"+
                                                        "attachment=false&"+
                                                        "gid=" + gid + "&"+
                                                        "r1=" + 0 + "&"+
                                                        "c1=" + 0 + "&"+
                                                        "r2=" + 62 + "&"+
                                                        "c2=" + 8;

var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();

// Creamos un fichero con el Blob anterior y le cambiamos el nombre 
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
var pdf = docurl.getBlob().setName(nombrePDF).getAs('application/pdf');

var folders = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFolders(); // En esta variable se almacenan solo los carpetas del directorio raiz
var nombrecarpeta = "DNIs de LP y Simulaciones";


  if(folders.hasNext() == false)//Para cuando no hay carpetas o folder aún en el Drive
  {
    var NewFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(nombrecarpeta);
    NewFolder.createFile(pdf);


      var file = NewFolder.createFile(pdf);
      Logger.log(file.getDownloadUrl());


  }
  else //En el caso de que sí haya carpetas o folder en el Drive, los recorre hasta encontrar el nombre "nombrecarpeta" sino lo encuentra la creará y ahí guarda el archivo
  {
    while (folders.hasNext())
    {
      var folder = folders.next();
      if(folder.getName() == nombrecarpeta)// en el caso de que exista una carpeta con el nombre terminamos la iteracion de las carpetas
    {
      var folderid = folder.getId();
      var Transfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
      Transfolder.createFile(pdf);

      var file = Transfolder.createFile(pdf);
      Logger.log(file.getDownloadUrl());

      break;
    }
    else 
    {// Creamos la carpeta en el caso de que aún no exista y guardamos el archivo en la nueva carpeta
      var NewFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(nombrecarpeta);
      NewFolder.createFile(pdf);
      var file = NewFolder.createFile(pdf);
      Logger.log(file.getDownloadUrl());
      break;
    }
   }   
  }

spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('LP con Seguros'), true);
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  //Obtiene el nombre del archivo PDF recién creado, así como su contenido
   var archivo = docurl.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').getBytes(); // sin la opción getBytes obtendríamos un archivo sin contenido
   var attach = {fileName:nombrePDF,content:archivo, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

   var subject = valRegisSimul + ' de Crédito Efectivo DNI ' + dni + ' ' + fecha;

   var html = '<body>' + '<strong>' + ' <p>Estimado(a)' + '</strong>' + '</p>' + 
      '<p>A continuación encontrará adjunto el archivo del plan de pagos de su Crédito Efectivo, recuerde siempre realizar los abonos al número de cuenta del préstamo.</p>' + 
      '<p style="text-align: left;">==> El número de cuenta del Crédito Efectivo a donde se deben hacer los abonos es: ' + '<strong>' + nrocuenta + '</strong>' + '</p>'

  //Muestra un Popup preguntando si deseas enviar la transferencia por correo  
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var response = ui.alert('Se completó el registro correctamente, ¿Desea enviar el plan de pagos al correo registrado: '+ correo + ' ?' + '\n\n' + 'Caso contrario, el archivo ' + nombrePDF + ' sólo se guardará en la carpeta ' + nombrecarpeta + ' de Drive', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  // Si la respuesta es si, mandará el correo, de lo contrario termina el programa
  if (response == ui.Button.YES)
  {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(correo, subject, "Cuerpo", {htmlBody:html, attachments:[attach]});
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Se envió correctamente el plan de pagos al correo '+ correo + '.' + '\n\n' + 'Mencione regreso por seguros y número de cuenta del Crédito efectivo');

     }else
     {
       //Solo por referencia
       Logger.log('El archivo '+ nombrePDF + ' quedó guardado en la carpeta ' + nombrecarpeta + ' de Drive');
     };

  var url = file.getDownloadUrl();
  var html = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">Para descargar el PDF con la simulación de pagos, haz clic aquí</a>';
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  var title = "Descargar PDF de Google Drive";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, title);

  }
```

PD. el Custom Dialog está al final del código.

```
  var url = file.getDownloadUrl();
  var html = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">Para descargar el PDF con la simulación de pagos, haz clic aquí</a>';
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  var title = "Descargar PDF de Google Drive";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, title);
```

Agradezco muchísimo de antemano las respuestas que reciba.
[image: Custom Dialog]
[image: Error al dar clic]

Comment: Es importante que desarrolles la habilidad de crear [mcve], primero porque te será útil para entender que está causando el error y clarificar que es lo que sabes y lo que no, y por otro, te ayudará a hacer preguntas específicas como se indica en [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de sacarle la vuelta al proeblema de `getDownloadUrl()` es usar un código como el siguiente

```
function doGet(e) {

  // id del archivo a descargar
  var id = 'remplazar con el id de tu pdf';

  // URL para descargar un archivo descargable de Google Drive
  var url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=' + id + '&export=download';

  // html como cadena de texto
  var html = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">Descargar</a>';

  // Enviar página web como respuesta al navegador
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);

}
```

Puedes obtener el id de tu objeto File usando `getId()`