# ¿Cómo puedo decirle al script que solo quiero que guarde el rango tamaño carta de la primer hoja?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Este código uso actualmente, solo que el problema es que guarda todo el libro... necesito guardar unicamente la hoja uno y tamaño carta (o el rango que abarca solo una hoja)

```
function PDFP()
{
var file = null;
var files = 
DriveApp.getFilesByName(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName());

if ( files.hasNext() )
file = files.next();

var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(file.getAs('application/pdf'));
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("F6").getValues();
var values2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("D11").getValues();

   Logger.log(values["F6"]);
   Logger.log(values2["D11"]);

   newFile.setName("No." + " " + values + " " + values2);

var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFiles();

while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var destination =DriveApp.getFolderById("1MZVNcUnoNs63_rDhCyydH8jZGLr5JjZO");
    destination.addFile(file);
    var pull = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    pull.removeFile(file);   

  Browser.msgBox(" Tu documento ha sido guardado con éxito. " , 
  Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }

  };
```

Espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

No es posible de hacerlo de forma directa pero puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma

1. Crear un nuevo spreadsheet

   - Hay dos métodos, uno que crea el spreadsheet con el número de filas y columnas predeterminado y otro para especificar cuantas debe tener el nuevo spreadsheet
2. Copiar el intervalo

   - Dependiendo de lo que necesites pasar, quizás debas primero crear una nueva hoja a la que copies el intervalo y luego copiar la hoja al nuevo spreadsheet. Si requieres sólo los datos puedes pasarlos directamente al nuevo spreadsheet
3. Ajustar las dimensiones

   - Dependiendo del como hayas realizado el paso anterior, quizás debas ajustar el ancho y altura de de columnas y filas respectivamente, quizás mas ajustes.
4. Guardar como PDF

   - Si has copiado una hoja primero deberas borrar la hoja predetermina luego creas el PDF como lo has hecho en tu código.

Referencias

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/drive-app

Relacionado

- [Script GAS Spreadsheet para crear y abrir/descargar PDF de Drive en Custom Dialog](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/313162/65)
- [Script GAS Spreadsheet - Crear y Descargar PDF guardado en Drive](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/312433/65)